# add value to select2 4 - empty entry becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 control in which I am adding data.
It's working well, the data is added.

However, the empty option that existed in the select suddenly becomes visible, wheras it's notin the beginning (norally you click the select 2 cross at the right of the control to erase your choice).

How can I do to make sure the empty option does not become visible when adding data ?

My code :

```
    <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary" id="launch">Lancer</a>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#launch').on('click', function(){
                var $select2 = $('#appbundle_job_offer_contact');
                $select2.select2({data: [{id: 'dada', text:'dada' }]});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

I have a feedle here which shows how the empty option is displayed : https://jsfiddle.net/v1skjwqy/1/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or the rest of your code. I just test your sample and it displays correctly.

Comment: hmmm, I've just built one and it works fine... I'll need to investigate this a bit more I guess : https://jsfiddle.net/v1skjwqy/

Comment: Did you originally initialize Select2 with a placeholder? That would have hid the blank option (and displayed the text), but would be reset when you are initializing Select2 again.

Comment: I actually understood I have to set a placeholder to hide the empty option: this is an answer, not a comment